# AngularJS - how to get an ngRepeat filtered result reference inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using an **ng-repeat** directive with filter like so:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="entry in (filteredEntries = (entries | filter:hasGroup | filter:readingFilter | orderBy:data.sortType:data.sortReverse:true))"></tr>
    <span>{{filteredEntries.length}}</span>
```

I'm using $stateProvider to load views and controllers

```
            $stateProvider
            .state('welcome', {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: viewsPrefix + "welcome.html",
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'Welcome'
                },
                controller: "WelcomeCtrl"
            })
            .state('data', {
                url: "/data",
                templateUrl: viewsPrefix + "data.html",
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'Data'
                },
                controller: "DataCtrl",
            })
```

Here is a snippet from my controller:

```
    .controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$translate', '$filter') {
$scope.filteredEntries = [];
$scope.entries = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7];
$scope.hasGroup = function(){return true;}
$scope.readingFilter = function(){return true;}
setInterval(function () {
   console.log($scope.filteredEntries);
}, 500);
});
```

There is no problem with such a code, however I need to access filteredEntries attribute in my controller using `$scope.filteredEntries` which should be ok with no problem. Unfortunately this didn't work and I couldn't figure it out why this is happening.

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question as it is currently presented.  You are asking why you cannot access the `filteredEntities` inside your controller.  However, filtering is an ordered process, and without knowing what your controller code looks like, it's not obvious what step in the process you are at when trying to access the data.  It is entirely possible that the data isn't filtered yet at the time you try to access the value.

Comment: Commenting rather than answering because this is not answer. You should consider just filtering the data in the controller using ng-change/watches to re-filter the data if needed. In angular2 the filter and orderBy filters are going away because doing this kind of thing in the view ends up looking ugly and it a efficiency drain. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html#!#filters-pipes for the decisions on those.

Comment: check that https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedsalah/z54rkg17/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can access the filtered array in BOTH VIEW AND CONTROLLER using this method:

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.people = ['fox', 'rosi', 'err3', 'rob', 'cesar', 'geoff'];
  
  vm.logPeople = function() {
    console.log("FILTERED PEOPLE: ", vm.filteredPeople);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <h2>List of people</h2>
    Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="person in vm.filteredPeople = (vm.people | filter:search)">
        {{person}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p ng-hide="vm.filteredPeople.length">There is no result</p>
    
    <button ng-click="vm.logPeople()">LOG PEOPLE</button>
    <br><br>
    Number of filtered people: {{vm.filteredPeople.length}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated for your example with updated code.

So, in your state provider for the data route, add "controllerAs: 'vm',":

```
    .state('data', {
        url: "/data",
        templateUrl: viewsPrefix + "data.html",
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Data'
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        controller: "DataCtrl",
    })
```

Then, in your controller:

```
.controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$translate', '$filter') {
var vm = this;

vm.filteredEntries = [];
vm.entries = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7];
vm.hasGroup = function(){return true;}
vm.readingFilter = function(){return true;}

vm.logEntries = function() {
  console.log("FILTERED Entries: ", vm.filteredEntries);
}

});
```

And finally, in your template (added button to test logging entries):

{{filteredEntries.length}}

```
<button ng-click="vm.logEntries()">LOG Entries</button>
<br><br>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work in my code for some reason. I updated my question to give you more global image

Comment: Give that a try. You can change vm to whatever you'd like.

Comment: It is worth nothing that while this answer does answers the question (which is the point of SO), doing assignment in an angular expressions in the view breaks mvc, and will be very difficult to unit test. It fails to make the controller view agnostic by forces the requirement that filtered people be assigned by the view the controller is working for. Rather than doing this at all, data should probably be prefiltered in the controller using ng-change/scope watches/ and event driven (e.g. ng-click) triggers.